# problem with new widget

Tags: magento-1.9, widgets

I'm trying to create a new widget. The development to admin works fine but not to frontend. Magento keep searching for my widget in mage. 
The widget.xml is aboce. Any clue/help?

Widget.xml

[image: widget.xml]

Show FAQs
        Show FAQs

** ERROR (is not in Mage)**
Warning: include(Mage\FAQs\Helper\Data.php): failed to open stream: No such file or directory  in C:\Projectos\WGM\lib\Varien\Autoload.php on line 94
and the widget wont appear in admin

With Widget.xml like this

[image: widget_v2.xml]

Show FAQs
        Show FAQs

I got no error when add the widget to a page via admin but when I call the page got an "exception 'Mage_Core_Exception' with message 'Tipo de Bloco inválido: Mage_FAQs_Block_Show' in C:\Projectos\WGM\app\Mage.php:595"

How can I tell Magento to find the widget in my module?
Thanks

[image: folders]

Comment: Tipo de Bloco inválido = invalid block type

Answer (score 1):

Your `etc/config.xml` must contain the correct block alias:

```
<global>

    <blocks>
        <FAQs>Tinsight_FAQs_Block</FAQs>
    </blocks>

</global>
```

Either it is missing or you did not use the right capitalization. It works in the backend because at this point, the block is not instantiated, so an invalid block alias does not cause errors.